# fullPage.js how to create a scroll to section when first page is not full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fullpage.js

I thought of using a script where you can scroll to a point/section with single wheel move.

I found the [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) but as it states in the name it works nicely when the sections (or at least first section) is set to full height. If not, when it scrolls down it leaves a bit of space - it works nicely only when you scroll up. Can maybe somebody help me with this?

The page can be seen here (sorry, it's in polish): http://tomhajduk.com/globke2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is a workaround and not clean! And it also seems to flicker a bit, but it seems to work...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGeGXZ

```
var lastSection=-1;
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      if (lastSection!=nextIndex) {
        lastSection=nextIndex;
        $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo(nextIndex+1);
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(nextIndex);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```